# How to make sure all dependencies in Gradle are compatible with each other in Android

Tags: java, android, gradle, dependencies

Most of the time I faced the issue where updating a library and all the other libraries are broken cause of incompatible version.

For instance, I have this code in the gradle build file:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.7'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.0'
```

If I changed retrofit version, to 1.9 for example, all the okhttp and gson stuff will broken.

The same thing happen when I work on a project with phonegap library or something similar.

Any idea how to always make sure that those libraries are compatible with each other?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try using this website http://gradleplease.appspot.com/

Comment: Thanks mate, not exactly what I am looking for but it partly sort out the issue.

Comment: Try use always the latest one , BUT , for firebase if you try run on AVD some times not work , for that i post a good solution , try find on my profile if you need